# Remove param type from function using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i am trying to remove param type from function using regex. I have this string

```
let str = 'function(param: Int, Window: String, param1: String, Window: String)';

console.log(str.replace(/(, )?Window: String/g, ''));
```

It removes and returns `function(param: Int, param1: String)` which is working fine but I do not want to hardcode `Window: String` in regex. it could be anything.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: So what do you want to remove? is it always the second parameter? or all of them? you could pass the name of param to remove as parameter to your function...

Comment: As of now its not working if `let str = 'function(param: Int, Window: Int, param1: String, Window: Int);` regex should be generic, it only accept String as of now/. it could be anywhere start, middle or end.

Comment: You only want to remove the Window one's?

Comment: please explain which parameters you wish your code to remove from the `str`

Comment: @Mohit Yes. i want to remove only Window

Comment: Are you looking for `/(, )?Window: \w+/g`? It'll allow the parameter **name** to be anything.

Comment: @ClasG yes. it is working. If this is string `let str = 'function(Window: Int, param: Int, Window: Int, param1: String, Window: Int)';

console.log(str.replace(/(, )?Window: \w+/g, ''));` then it gives `function(, param: Int, param1: String)` it should give `function(param: Int, param1: String)`

Comment: You also can put the params in an array, delete the unwanted param with its row and put it back into a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with an alternation, like this:

```
/,\s*Window:\s*\w+|\s*Window:\s*\w+\s*,\s*?/g
```

This will attempt to handle commas before the parameter first, and if that doesn't match, it tries to match without the comma before the parameter, but with an **optional** comma after.

```js
console.log('function(param: Int, Window: String, param1: String, Window: String)'.replace(/,\s*Window:\s*\w+|\s*Window:\s*\w+\s*,\s*?/g, ''));
console.log('function(Window: Int, param: Int, Window: Int, param1: String, Window: Int)'.replace(/,\s*Window:\s*\w+|\s*Window:\s*\w+\s*,?\s*/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without reg expression first try:

```js
let paramToDel = 'Window';

let str = 'function(param: Int, Window: String, param1: String, Window: String)';
    
function delParam(str, param)
{
  str = str.trim();  
  params = str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1, str.indexOf(')'));
  params = params.replace(/([a-z0-9]+)/ig, '"$1"');  
  let res = JSON.parse('{'+params+'}');
  delete res[param];
  res = JSON.stringify(res);
  return 'function('+res.substring(1, res.length-1).replace(/"/g, '')+')';
}
    
console.log('Input', '`' + str + '`')
console.log('Output', '`' + delParam(str, paramToDel) + '`');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```